# Using simple_form, how do I render a 'new' form on the view of another controller in a DRY way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a `_form.html.erb` partial, for my `DailyEntry` model that looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@daily_entry) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :breakfast %>
    <%= f.input :snack_1 %>
    <%= f.input :lunch %>
    <%= f.input :snack_2 %>
    <%= f.input :dinner %>
    <%= f.input :water_intake %>
    <%= f.input :workout %>
    <%= f.input :notes %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Each `DailyEntry` belongs to a `User`...i.e. each `daily_entry` record has a `user_id` column.

I would like for the `current_user` to be able to add a `daily_entry` from the `Home#Index` page - WITHOUT duplicating the `create` action of my `DailyEntry` controller.

So how do I kill 2 birds with one stone? i.e. assign the newly created `daily_entry` record to the current user, and then also have this all done from my `views/home/index.html.erb`?

**Edit 1**

I know how to assign each record to a user....in the `DailyEntry` controller `create` action, I have this:

```
def create
  @daily_entry = current_user.daily_entries.create(params[:daily_entry])

respond_to do |format|
  if @daily_entry.save
    format.html { redirect_to @daily_entry, notice: 'Daily entry was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @daily_entry, status: :created, location: @daily_entry }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @daily_entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

I am just not sure how to get this done from my `Home#Index.html.erb`. How do I render this form without duplicating that controller logic in my `HomeController`?

**Edit 2**

I also tried this:

```
<%= render partial: "daily_entries/form", @daily_entry => current_user.daily_entries.build  %>
```

But I still get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

At line:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@daily_entry) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create` action on your daily_entries controller is where your form action points to, and this is not going to change.

To render the form on the index page, all you have to do is build the `@daily_entry` object in your home_controller:

```
# home_controller.rb
def index
    @daily_entry = DailyEntry.new
end

# home/index.html.erb
<%= render "daily_entries/form" %>
```

Comment: Yeh I am trying to avoid that...i.e. trying to avoid having to duplicate the `DailyEntry` controller functionality in my `Home` controller.